# TNS oracle connection failed from MVC3 site using ASP.NET Membership provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, oracle, asp.net-membership, connection-string, tnsnames

We have an MVC3 site that uses the ASP.NET Membership Provider with Forms Authentication to let users onto the site.  We have an Oracle database behind it.

It all works in house on development machines, test machines and deployment machines.

But at a client - they are getting the error "ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified".

We thought this would be a simple case of a wrong config entry but all seems correct.  They've also run a tnsping to the same TNS alias and it works.  A connection via SQL*Plus also works.  We've even got them to download a .NET connection string tester application and that connects ok using exactly the same connection string as the MVC3 site web.config has.  It's only the website that comes back with this error. (note: all the tests were done from the same machine as the website is on)

Has anyone seen this before and provide some guidance on how to solve?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked if account `IUSR_yourmachinename` has read permissions to `youroraclehome\NETWORK\ADMIN\TNSNAMES.ORA`?

Comment: They say that the tnsnames.ora and the sqlnet.ora files both have read permissions for "everyone".  I did notice that their tnsnames.ora file and sqlnet.ora files are on a network drive and are accessed via a UNC path - will this make a difference?

Comment: I suspect that the account under which the application runs cannot access the network share. I suggest performing a test by implementing a page that attempts to read the TNSNAMES file at its network location to display success or the resulting error. I suspect that your test will result in the latter on that machine.

Comment: Spot on Vadim - we created a sample MVC app as you suggested and found that it was the user the AppPool was being run by (right click on the AppPool, click 'advanced settings' and look at the 'Identity') that didn't have access to the tnsnames file over the network.

Comment: @VadimK. if you add in a proper answer with the text from your comments, I will accept it as the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The likely cause for this, from experience, is that the account under which the application is running is unable to read/access the `TNSNAMES.ORA` file, either due to file/folder permissions or network access permissions.